# Standard deviation of point pattern

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-10.3, spatial-statistics

I am using ArcGIS software to create a Standard deviation of point pattern, and I know whether Ii need to expect a circle or an ellipse.

Is standard deviation in that context always circular? And if it is, what is the best / normal way to describe it (diameter? radius? and what is the Greek letter for it)? And would mean center always be the center-point of this circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the Gong (2010) paper "[Clarifying the Standard Deviational Ellipse](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1538-4632.2002.tb01082.x/abstract)" which describe the geometry behind this statistic. And no, the standard deviation ellipse is not necessarily an ellipse but, rather a curve function.

Folks need to quit paying attention to ESRI and start reading the primary literature!

Gong, J., (2010) Clarifying the Standard Deviational Ellipse. Geographical Analysis 34(2):155-167